# Clone a div.row, and set all <select> elements in it to first option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I clone a row like so:

```
var row = $("#seminar-registrations div.row.seminar-registrant:first-child").clone();
```

And that row has `<select>` elements in it, and I want to re set them all to the first option before I use `appendTo()`

How can I do this?

Comment: @Satpal thank you but no that didnt work.

Comment: Dont know why this is getting down voted, it's a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/18347/), but like tells you @Satpal, will made by other ways

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
      $("#el").clone().find('select').val($(this).find('option:eq(0)').val()).appendTo('#content');

})

});
```